# Is it dangerous to allow user to give arguments to ndb.Query()?

Tags: security, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm writing a search tool, and one of the things I have to do is to let the user search for ndb objects.

Is it dangerous to let the user choose arguments to the `ndb.Query()` function? Can it be used to modify or delete data?

Since I can supply the `kind` argument, the result set would be limited to some types. Also, writing a small parser/validator will help security-wise as well. I just want to make sure I don't do anything too stupid here. A grammar to follow would be awesome, if anyone has it.

Comment: GQL only allows querying for data, not deleting/modifying, so you are safe in that regard. However, keep in mind that malicious code could return data that was not intended. If you expand your questions with some examples of what you are doing, it might be easier to give a good response ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments to the `ndb.Query` constructor cannot modify nor delete data.  They could easily crash this instance of your server, if erroneous, or provide access to data you might not want that user to see, e.g by an undesired `namespace` setting -- but that's about the worst of it.

Nevertheless I'd consider having the constructor unencumbered and using explicit `filter` and maybe `order` calls to let the user indirectly customize the query -- they more highly constrained and I suspect those are your key points for query customization anyway, right?

And, it's easier to avoid a crash (be it malicious or accidental) by wrapping such calls into appropriate `try`/`except` blocks to provide accurate diagnosis of user errors...